# ActiveX fails to load a library even if it is in the same location

Tags: c#, dll, mfc, activex, ocx

I am maintaining an ActiveX control developed in MFC to be used as a plug-in for a multiple of commercial applications.  This was all working perfectly until I wanted AES encryption included because the control needs to logon to a remote location automatically.  No big deal, created a C# class library (SimpleAES.dll) that only provides a class with 2 members, encrypt and decrypt.  Mixing managed and unmanaged code, I wrote a wrapper library in C++/CLR wrapping my encryption class (SimpleAESWrapper.dll).

This all works like a charm when tested using my ocx test container application, storing all 3 libraries in the same directory as the test container application (that is the test.exe together with ocx, together with the two dll's).

Unfortunately when I run a third party application, that loads the ocx, the ocx will not get loaded because it does crash as soon as I create an instance of the encryption class due to the fact that it cannot find the WrapperSimpleAES.dll. The third party application is ran from another location.  Adding the libraries location to the path or even system32 folder does not resolve the issue.

Am I missing something crucial, like do the libraries have to be registered in some way like the ocx has to with regsvr32.exe? i.e. Applications know where to find the ocx because it is registered into the registry right?

I have been pulling my hair out as I can nowhere find a useful lead.

Comment: Is the DLL implicitly loaded. Or are you calling LoadLibrary? Try to debug the target process and look into the Output window. What is written there, when the code is executed.

Comment: Thanks xMRI: The wrapper is statically loaded with its lib, I do not use a LoadLibrary, the wrapper in turn has the class library as a reference.  Debugging the target is a bit complicated as the third party application is installed on a remote machine (not ours) which I access remotely.  There is no crash whatsoever it just doesn't load the active X which it does as soon I remove the instance of the encryption object (which is an instance coming from the wrapper).

Comment: This is pretty normal, Windows has no reason to look in the directory where the COM server is located.  However, if adding the directory to the path doesn't work then you have Bigger Problems.  You'll need SysInterals' ProcMon to have a look-see where Windows looks for the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the WrapperSimpleAES.dll in the 3rd party program directory.

Comment: Thanks thomiel: Unfortunately the 3rd party application is a Java application, making the directory in this case System32 where the javaws.exe resides.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you ActiveX Control is found by a LoadLibrary call. COM resolves the needed DLL via the registry entries. Your Problem now, is that when your code executes the next DLL needed isn't found.

As a Workaround:

1. Set your secondary DLL as delay load. So it is not needed when your ActiveX Control loads.
2. When your ActiveX needs the secondary DLL use GetDllDirectory to get the current Setting and save it.
3. Now use SetDllDirectory to the Path of your main ActiveX.
4. Execute your code. The Delay-Load will succeed.
5. After the call use SetDllDirectory to restore the old settings.

HTH

Comment: although I have no clue why the OS doesn't find the dll when the directory is already in the Path environment variable, I've applied the  /DELAYLOAD:"SimpleAES.dll" option on the SimpleAESWrapper.dll project and I did use the function SetDllDirectory just in front of creating an instance of the SimpleAESWrapper object in my ocx, yet to no avail. I have the impression that the dll is already loaded before doing that somehow.

Comment: Let the Client run. Attach the Debugger to the Project and look what happens. Also you can Monitor what DLLs ae loaded.

Comment: I think I have a fair idea of what's happening, I just don't know why: simply putt, consider exe that loads a wrapper dll (statically or delay loaded won't matter), wrapping a C# class library, the wrapper will always be found, but the class library not, even if it is in the same folder as the wrapper. If the exe is in another directory, it will crash, if it is in the same directory it works.
The missing link is: how to let the wrapper load the C# class library?

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote, as my answer. My try was to fix this second load of the DLL in the way that SetDllDirectory is set to the path were the second DLL has to be found!

Comment: Yes but the SetDllDirectory doesn't seem to do the trick, it merely sets the path for Windows to find the dll which for some reason is not sufficient?